# Computer fails to boot properly after vmware workstation 9 was installed on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 3.5.0-27-generic on an HP dm4-1028tx. I just reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 after encountering problems with Ubuntu 12.10. I was installing VMware Workstation 9 after uninstalling VMware player when it crashed and rebooted and I ended up with the screen shown in the pictures below:

[image]
[image]

I managed to uninstall workstation via the root shell but I'd still like to be able to install it again. Has anyone faced the same problem? Any tips on how to debug the issue?

Comment: Have you filed this as a bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug vmware-manager' in Terminal? (I don't know how to fix this sorry).

Comment: Should this be filed against vmware-manager or vmware-workstation?

Comment: I assume vmware-workstation (sorry for the late reply)